# Call a function when a view controller is on top

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

I'm wondering if there is a method that would call when a view controller is loaded to the screen.

As an example, the user presses a button and a second view controller loads. When the view controller appears, it runs a function automatically.

Comment: You can take advantage of `-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{}` of the ViewController being loaded on the screen. This will wait until it shows on the screen to execute the code

Comment: I've added an answer with other methods that may be helpful to you if you need them to run at different times of the viewController life cycle!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several methods you can use in a ViewController to run functions depending when you need them to run. In your case, you should use

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

This will run once the viewController is appearing on the screen. Be sure to also call `[super viewDidAppear:animated]` inside the method.

Other methods that may come in handy:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
-(void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: It is worth noting that viewDidLoad will only run once each time you present a view controller, whereas the other methods will be called every time the view controller appears/disappears.  For instance if your view controllers are in a navigation controller stack and you pop the top view controller, viewDidLoad will not run again on the VC that was underneath it.  Similarly, if you have a UITabBarController and you toggle between view controllers, viewDidLoad will only run the first time you load each one, but viewWillAppear will run every time you toggle.